# Celery Deadlock when saving data in Django, why?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a **Deadlock** when using a **Celery** task to save new customers from a CSV. This is what I have working so far.

```
  for line in csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines()):
        for index, item in enumerate(line):
            number = int(item)
            # TODO: Turn into task
            Customer.objects.create_customer(
                mobile=number,
                campaign=instance.campaign,
                reward_group=instance.reward_group,
                company=instance.company,
            )
```

No errors.

However, when add this same code to a Celery task I get the following error...

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'

So, this leads me to believe that I have done something wrong with my celery setup here. Can anyone spot what?

Here is the new Celery task that gives the deadlock error. I'm using `shared_task` as these task will at some point run on a different machine without Django, but that should not matter for now.

The first row in the CSV import ok, then I get a deadlock error...

```
for line in csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines()):
    for index, item in enumerate(line):
        number = int(item)
        celery_app.send_task('test.tasks.create_customer_from_import', args=[number, instance.id], kwargs={})
```

**tasks.py**

```
# Python imports
from __future__ import absolute_import

# Core Django imports
from celery import shared_task

from mgm.core.celery import app as celery_app

@shared_task
def create_customer_from_import(number, customer_upload_id):
    customer_upload = CustomerUpload.objects.get(pk=customer_upload_id)
    new_customer = Customer.objects.create_customer(
        mobile=number,
        campaign=customer_upload.campaign,
        reward_group=customer_upload.reward_group,
        company=customer_upload.company,
    )
    return new_customer
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test.settings')

app = Celery('test-tasks')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**This is the CustomerManager:**

```
class CustomerManager(models.Manager):
    def create_customer(self, mobile, campaign, reward_group, company, password=None):.
        user = AppUser.objects.create_user(mobile=mobile)
        # Creates a new customer for a company and campaign
        customer = self.model(
            user=user,
            campaign=campaign,
            reward_group=reward_group,
            company=company
        )

        customer.save(using=self._db)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't look wrong, but you're probably getting the deadlock because of the concurrency of multiple celery workers. From http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#mysql-is-throwing-deadlock-errors-what-can-i-do:

> MySQL has default isolation level set to REPEATABLE-READ, if you don’t
>   really need that, set it to READ-COMMITTED. You can do that by adding
>   the following to your my.cnf:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
> ```

Comment: I managed to change the setting and verify it using the statement ``SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'tx_isolation';`` but I get the same deadlock I'm afraid. I restarted MySQL server also. Has to be something else going on here. So does celery do this in one go, I assumed that it read/writes and releases as its the same row table it should not deadlock but wait until released, thats my understanding.

Comment: Could you run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to see the cause of the most recent deadlock? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: Thats cool, I did not know about the command ``SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS``. ``READ-COMMITTED`` did work I needed to set the actual file. Anyone know what the disadvantages are of READ-COMMITTED?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read and http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/